# Beginner questions about Frtos compiler(s)

Tags: freertos

I want to learn FreeRtos I just started reading some pdf books online. I'm a total beginner in this area and I have a question:

I have googled and found out that "Visual Studio 2010 Express" compiler supports FreeRtos. Does that mean that If I write some C FreeRTOS code in this compiler just like I would do a normal .c program will it work fine? Also please explain what is a "port" when talking about RTOS.

Please help me clear this up as I'm planning to start compiling the examples that I read in my pdf books. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answer from @Richard indicates the FreeRTOS can be used in a Windows environment, this is not a typical use case.

FreeRTOS is generally used in an embedded microcontroller (i.e., appliances, peripherals, toys, industrial controllers, etc.) where there is no other operating system present. It provides basic functions for managing multiple tasks for time-critical functions.

If you have not yet done any embedded development, I would recommend choosing a microcontroller development board and learning how to develop simple stuff for it first, and then add FreeRTOS into the mix. This can be a steep but rewarding learning curve.

An embedded application is standard C, but it is not a "normal C program" in the sense you would run on your PC. You compile and flash the program to the chip, and it will automatically execute `main()` upon power up or reset. There is no separate OS, and you typically do not have `stdio` or any PC-like user interface. Your application is the only thing running and is responsible for literally *everything*. Libraries like FreeRTOS help with some complex or difficult tasks, or simple but common tasks. (The chip manufacturer will provide libraries for configuring and controlling its basic functions.)

A FreeRTOS "port" is an adaptation of FreeRTOS to a particular microcontroller family, tailoring it to the specific timers, control registers, or other hardware capabilities (or lack thereof) the chip provides. The core FreeRTOS files are unchanged, and you will choose the "port" files based on the chip you are using. Your application will include and link to the necessary FreeRTOS code files just like any other library.

Regarding compilers and other development tools, you will use whatever normal tools for the target chip. Visual Studio Express isn't really intended to be used for embedded development, and I don't believe it supports it out of the box (no cross-compiler). I have used a third-party plugin called [VisualGDB](https://visualgdb.com/), with an [STM32 Discovery](http://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32-mcu-discovery-kits.html) board to compile and run simple FreeRTOS-based applications - this worked quite well, and was easy to get running.

Ultimately I found this to be an uncommon solution, and hard to find help when I got stuck. I am transitioning to the standard [GNU ARM Toolchain](https://developer.arm.com/open-source/gnu-toolchain/gnu-rm) (with Visual Studio Code as an editor), and working through the tool learning curve myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run FreeRTOS in a Windows environment, but don't expect real time behaviour when you do.  The FreeRTOS scheduler will be scheduling the tasks like normal, but ultimately it will be running in a Windows process, which Windows itself has control over.  If you are reading the latest book (available for free download) then it tells you about this and the examples are already pre-configured to run in the windows (simulator) environment.  You can also find out more about running FreeRTOS in a Windows process here: http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Windows-Simulator-Emulator-for-Visual-Studio-and-Eclipse-MingW.html